# WPF RichTextBox scroll to TextPointer

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, richtextbox

The WPF RichtTextBox has a method to scroll:

```
RichTextBox.ScrollToVerticalOffset(double)
```

I want to scroll in such a way, that a certain range or at least the start of it comes into view. How can I convert a TextPointer to double in a meaningful way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the FrameworkElement.BringIntoView Method. I'm using something like this:

```
public void Foo(FlowDocumentScrollViewer viewer) {
    TextPointer t = viewer.Selection.Start;
    FrameworkContentElement e = t.Parent as FrameworkContentElement;
    if (e != null)
         e.BringIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm somewhat late, but here is a more complete answer. The current scroll offsets need to be combined with the character position. Here is an example that scrolls RichTextBox text pointer to the center of the view:

```
var characterRect = textPointer.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
RichTextBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(RichTextBox.HorizontalOffset + characterRect.Left - RichTextBox.ActualWidth / 2d);
RichTextBox.ScrollToVerticalOffset(RichTextBox.VerticalOffset + characterRect.Top - RichTextBox.ActualHeight / 2d);
```

You don't need to check for negative numbers, as the scrolling accounts for this.

Answer (score 3):

Use GetCharacterRect to get position of TextPointer in RichTextBox:

```
Rect r = textPointer.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Backward);
rtb.ScrollToVerticalOffset(r.Y);
```

Answer (score 2):

So if you're wondering why `BringIntoView()` isn't working or it scrolls to the top of your textbox, it's likely because you are attempting to "bring into view" the `Inline` that comprises your entire scrollable text content - it "brings to view" this inline, which starts at (you guessed it) the "start" `TextPosition` at the top.

Solution is to use `ScrollToVerticalOffset()` per [Miroslav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32865673/9362652).